# How to pass a variable in Jenkins Credentials Helper Function

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

```
 environment {
    BRANCH_NAME = "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
    DEPLOYMENT_MACHINE = credentials('auto-deployment')
}
```

*How to pass Variable to credentials Function like*

```
environment {
    BRANCH_NAME = "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
    DEPLOYMENT_MACHINE = credentials("${BRANCH_NAME}")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`"${exp}"` is [Groovy String interpolation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation), it is an alternative to `"" + exp + ""`.

thus you can simply do

`def deploymentBranchCred = credential(env.BRANCH_NAME)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 environment {    
    DEPLOYMENT_MACHINE = credentials("${env.BRANCH_NAME}")
    BRANCH = "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
}
```

It's Working Fine.! issue with BRANCH_NAME as declared again in the environment.